# How do I get a default value to display in the template with django?

Tags: django, templates, view, model

I am using a modelform to extend a user's profile.  I would like previously saved data to show up in the form before the user decides to write over it.  How do I do this in the template with django?

## model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    quote = models.CharField('About', max_length =  200, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField('Personal website/blog', null=True, blank=True)
    
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('quote', 'website')
        widgets = {
            'quote': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 18, 'rows': 7, 'style': "width: 300px;"}),
        }
```

## view

```
@login_required 
def user_profile(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upform = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if upform.is_valid():
            up = upform.save(commit=False)
            up.user = request.user
            up.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        upform = UserProfileForm()
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/edit_profile.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## template

```
{{ upform.as_p}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `instance=user.get_profile()` to `UserProfileForm` when you instantiate it.

Comment: I changed it to "upform = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user.get_profile())".  Do I have to change anything in the template?

Comment: You should show us your template to know if it has to be changed

Comment: @armonge All I have right now in the template that is related to the form is what's listed above.  I'm not sure how to edit it to include the default data (data already entered by the user).

Comment: The code I gave you instantiates the form with the current saved data as initial values for the field. All you have to do is just dump the form into the template. The template code you have right now merely prints the `input` element for the `website` field, it doesn't output the entire form. You can simply use something like `{{ form.as_p }}` to drop the whole thing on the page, or use `{% for field in form %}` to render each field individually.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I replaced what's in the template currently with simply "{{ upform.as_p }}" and the default value text in the textbox/textarea still isn't being rendered.

Comment: If you don't want your users change other users profiles, replace user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id) with user = request.user

Comment: To let get_profile() work: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: @sharataka: perhaps you should repost your code as you currently have it. You should have initial values if you set `instance=user.get_profile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `instance=profile` in BOTH places that you instantiate the form. To make that a bit easier, you can create a dict and use the `**` keyword expansion operator:

```
@login_required 
def user_profile(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    form_kwargs = {}
    try:
        form_kwargs['instance'] = user.get_profile()
    except Profile.DoesNotExist(): # change Profile to whatever your profile model is named
        pass

    if request.method == 'POST':
        upform = UserProfileForm(request.POST, **form_kwargs)
        if upform.is_valid():
            up = upform.save(commit=False)
            up.user = request.user
            up.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        upform = UserProfileForm(**form_kwargs)
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/edit_profile.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

The form expects a UserProfile instance if you pass one, not a user instance.

You have two (or more) options to pass a UserProfile instance to your form.

**Option 1 get_or_create**

You can use get_or_create. It gets the profile, if it doesnt exist it creates and saves one.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create

```
userprofile=UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

then pass userprofile to both calls to of UserProfileForm

```
upform = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=userprofile)
upform = UserProfileForm(instance=userprofile)
```

**Option 2 get_profile()**

A few things to check, if you want to use user.get_profile() you need to make sure your user profile is set up correctly as given here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Mainly, in your settings.py that you have set:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "account.UserProfile"
```

this assumes that UserProfile is defined in the app called "*account*", if its in MyApp instead:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "MyApp.UserProfile"
```

then you can use (as stated earlier):

```
upform = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.get_profile())
upform = UserProfileForm(instance= instance=request.user.get_profile())
```

though you will need to handle the instance that the user has not created a profile yet, here get_profile() will fail, as would UserProfile.objects.get.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just pass user as an instance in the form:

```
@login_required 
...
    else:
        upform = UserProfileForm(instance=user)
...
```

You may then need to manually build your template:

so

```
Quote: {{ upform.quote }}
```

should output the already 'saved' quote.